# Getting ClassNotFoundException in tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, tomcat

I am getting classnotfoundexception, but same class is available in WEB-INF/lib folder .jar file. Facing this issue in tomcat 8.5

Comment: Have you tried with clean and build the project?
And please update your question with some logs or complete Exception you have seen so we can determine your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the works directory and find your folder containing your webApplication and in which you must place your Class which is actually needed to resolve this exception!